# Is it possible add a group to selection (not selection to a group) in the in 3d viewport?

Tags: selection-tools, groups

Is it possible to add a object group to selection **(not selection to a object group)** in the 3d viewport? I know it can be done in the outliner, but I would rather some sort of shift click function in the viewport similar to how add objects to selection is done in the 3d viewport. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would it be <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> > *Select Grouped > Group > Group Name*?

After executing the operator, on the bottom of the tools panel or pressing <kbd>F6</kbd> you can open the operator properties and tick the *Extend* option to extend current selection

Comment: Yes but if i wanted to select another group and keep the first group selected, how could I do that in the 3d viewport and not the outliner? Is this possible without using the outliner?

Comment: This operator adds to current selection as far as I know. If you have other objects selected before selecting grouped those will be kept, and selecting grouped will append them to current selection.

Comment: Thats what I think it should do, but Its not working for me.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aGdH.gif

Comment: Use the *Extend* option in the operator properties. See updated answer above